# Gulp task throwing ENOTEMPTY error in console

Tags: gulp

I'm running some Gulp tasks, and I'm having trouble fully cleaning my dist/ folder after I run a clean task using the del npm module, as recommended by Gulp for deleting folders and files. My Gulpfile.js is as follows:

```
// Setup modules/Gulp plugins
var gulp            = require('gulp'),
    del             = require('del'),
    less            = require('gulp-less'),
    minifyCSS       = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    fileinclude     = require('gulp-file-include'),
    streamify       = require('gulp-streamify'),
    order           = require('gulp-order'),
    concat          = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify          = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sourcemaps      = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    imagemin        = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant        = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    plumber         = require('gulp-plumber'),
    connect         = require('gulp-connect');

// Configure file paths
var path = {
    DEST: 'dist/',
    SRC: 'src/',
    INCLUDES: 'include/',
    LESS_SRC: 'src/frontend/less/',
    LESS_MANIFEST: 'src/frontend/less/all.less',
    CSS_DEST: 'dist/frontend/css/',
    JS_SRC: 'src/frontend/js/',
    JS_MINIFIED_OUT: 'all.js',
    JS_DEST: 'dist/frontend/js',
    IMG_SRC: 'src/frontend/img/',
    IMG_DEST: 'dist/frontend/img/',
};

// Clean out build folder each time Gulp runs
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    del([
        path.DEST
    ], cb);
});

// Compile LESS
gulp.task('less', function(){
    return gulp.src(path.LESS_MANIFEST)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.CSS_DEST));
    // Copy src folders into dist folder
    // gulp.src(path.LESS_SRC + '**')
        // .pipe(gulp.dest(path.CSS_DEST + 'less/'));
});

// Allow HTML files to be included
gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src([path.SRC + '*.html'])
        .pipe(connect.reload())
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(fileinclude({
            prefix: '@@',
            basepath: path.INCLUDES
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST));
});

// Concatenate and minify JavaScript
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.JS_SRC + '**/*.js')
        .pipe(order([
            path.JS_SRC + 'framework/*.js',
            path.JS_SRC + 'vendor/*.js',
            path.JS_SRC + 'client/*.js'
        ], {base: '.'} ))
        .pipe(concat(path.JS_MINIFIED_OUT))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.JS_DEST));
});

// Minify images
gulp.task('imagemin', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.IMG_SRC + '*')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            use: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.IMG_DEST));
});

// Copy folders
gulp.task('copy', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.SRC + 'extjs/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST + 'extjs/'));
});

// Watch files
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(path.LESS_SRC + '**/*.less', ['less']);
    gulp.watch(path.SRC + '*.html', ['html']);
    gulp.watch(path.JS_SRC + '**/*.js', ['js']);
});

// Connect to a server and livereload pages
gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: path.DEST,
        livereload: true
    });
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', [
                    'clean',
                    'less',
                    'html',
                    'js',
                    'imagemin',
                    'copy',
                    'watch',
                    'connect'
                    ]);
```

Usually everytime I run this I'm getting some kind of error in the console and it doesn't fully delete the dist/ folder after running `gulp` in the terminal.

```
[14:34:12] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/outerbox/odot/Gulpfile.js
[14:34:12] Starting 'clean'...
[14:34:12] Starting 'less'...
[14:34:12] Starting 'html'...
[14:34:12] Starting 'js'...
[14:34:12] Starting 'imagemin'...
[14:34:12] Starting 'copy'...
[14:34:12] Starting 'watch'...
[14:34:12] Finished 'watch' after 16 ms
[14:34:12] Starting 'connect'...
[14:34:12] Finished 'connect' after 7.64 ms
[14:34:12] Server started http://localhost:8080
[14:34:12] LiveReload started on port 35729
[14:34:13] Finished 'html' after 303 ms
[14:34:13] 'clean' errored after 360 ms
[14:34:13] Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/Users/jacobtarr/Desktop/outerbox/odot/dist'
    at Error (native)
[14:34:13] 'js' errored after 340 ms
[14:34:13] Error: ENOENT, stat '/Users/jacobtarr/Desktop/outerbox/odot/dist/frontend/js/all.js'
    at Error (native)
[14:34:13] 'copy' errored after 330 ms
[14:34:13] Error: ENOENT, stat '/Users/jacobtarr/Desktop/outerbox/odot/dist/extjs/ext-all.js'
    at Error (native)
[14:34:13] Finished 'less' after 388 ms
[14:34:14] gulp-imagemin: Minified 30 images (saved 139.74 kB - 17.5%)
[14:34:14] Finished 'imagemin' after 1.49 s
```

How do I fix this error? And how would I go about properly flushing out the dist/ folder before running gulp?

Comment: The problem is because your root file path in the connect task is the same as the folder you want to delete. In the meantime, gulp connect is running, which means the file is in use.

Comment: @generalgmt Thanks for the feedback, but when I removed that root property from the connect task, I'm still getting that ENOTEMPTY error and it's not performing the clean task before any of my other tasks.

Comment: i will suggest to try this... first do the clean and then run other tasks... dont run it in parallel with other tasks